# A simple question about homomorphisms between finite groups and free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-homomorphism, adjoint-functors

I am currently studying adjoint functors, on the book "Advanced Modern Algebra", the author shows by a counterexample that $(U,F)$ is not an adjoint pair of functors,where $U$ and $F$ denote the underlying functor and the free functor, respectively.

The counterexample given by Rotman is:

If $H$ is a finite group with more than one element and $Y$ is a set with more than one element, then ${\rm Hom}_{Sets} (UH,Y)$ has more than one element, but ${\rm Hom}_{Groups} (H,FY)$ has only one element. Therefore, $(U,F)$ is not an adjoint functor.

---

My doubt:

It is not that straightforward for me to observe that there is only one homomorphism between $H$ and $FY$, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The nontrivial elements of $FY$ have infinite order. The elements of $H$, and hence their images under any group homomorphism, have finite order. So the only map from a finite group to a free group is the trivial map.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh I see...Thank you so much!